# Click link with href="javascript:void(0);" using PowerShell

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

What I am trying to do is create a web script in PowerShell which navigates to one page and clicks on a link to redirect to another page. The issue I am having is when you click on the link manually, it properly takes you to a specific AllRegs page. However when the link is clicked with Click() by the script, it instead takes you to the AllRegs home page which I do not want. Is this a session issue? Anyone know of a possible solution?

The issue seems to lie in the fact that the href of the link is **href="javascript:void(0);** rather than a normal url

URL of first page: http://www.freddiemac.com/singlefamily/guide/

Here is a screenshot of the link I am trying to click(), highlighted in yellow.
[image: Link highlighted in yellow]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what method are you using for your script? ie com object might work for this

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried both com object and Invoke Web Request. Neither take me to the proper site

Comment: pretty sure you wont get far with invoke-webrequest, the com object should work though. you might just be clicking the wrong link, did you make sure you dont?

Comment: Yes, I have made sure I am clicking on the <a> tag